# iOS app scan BLE device on background

Tags: ios, background

my app using scanForPeripheralsWithServices: to scan BLE device,the argument is specified servicesUUIDs array, sometimes could discover peripheral quickly,but sometimes need to wait for a moment.And my app is session backgrounding.Then,how can I discoverPeripherals as quickly as possible on background.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in the background iOS is enabling Bluetooth from time to time and it is not always listening. This is to save battery and because the WiFi and Bluetooth share the same antenna and cannot send at the same time. To make it discover your peripheral as fast as possible you should if you have access to peripheral implementation, make sure the peripheral advertises itself as often as possible. I believe Apple recommends at least once each 20th ms.